# Boto3 s3 python upload_file retrying repeatedly

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

My process

1. s3 file upload triggers lambda function
2. lambda function edits the doc
3. save document object to tmp folder
4. upload to s3 output folder as a file

Everything works and there's no error but the file is uploaded to the output folder every couple of seconds until I retrigger the lambda function.

I've pinpointed the problem to be the upload_file function. I've tried adding the Config arg (use_threads = True).

```
try:

  document.save('/tmp/'+key)
  s3.upload_file('/tmp/'+newkey, bucket,'Output/'+newkey)

except Exception as e:

  print(e)
  raise e
```

Comment: _Everything works and there's no error but the file is uploaded to the output folder every couple of seconds until I retrigger the lambda function._ Is that the issue? Please share all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my mistake. This lambda function goes in a loop because it triggers itself from the file upload into the same bucket in step 4. Using a new bucket for the output file fixed the issue.